# Configuring android sdk in Dreamweaver Cs 5.5

Tags: android, cordova, configuration, dreamweaver

I am having this strange problem and cannot figure it out. While configuring I put Android SDK path as: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk (this is where android-sdk is installed) and saved it.
In Select Target OS version: Android drop down list is empty!(I have three AVDs and it works in Eclipse ok, Android 2.2 API 8, Android 2.3.3 API 10 and Android 4.4.2 API 19) when I click Manage AVDs in Dream Weaver nothing happens. No AVDs are shown, though they are there. Where am I going wrong ? Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem. Moved android-sdk to C:\Android\android-sdk all Avds load normally.

Now when I try to build the application it doesn't build instead I get this build log;

```
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\Configuration\NativeAppFramework\apache-ant
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
____________________
</DW>
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *

* daemon started successfully *

List of devices attached 



Launching the Android emulator
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\Configuration\NativeAppFramework\apache-ant
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Android\android-sdk\tools
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /u /c "C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe -partition-size 1024 -cpu-delay 0 -no-boot-anim -avd Froyo"
____________________
</DW>
Cloning seed app for Android
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\Configuration\NativeAppFramework\apache-ant
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Users\Ranjan\Desktop\com.rmworks.pension_calculator_Android
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /u /c C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\Configuration\NativeAppFramework\DWPhoneGap\android\scripts\droidGap.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\Configuration\NativeAppFramework\DWPhoneGap\android\PhoneGapApp" "Pension Calculator" com.rmworks.pension_calculator 1.0 "C:\Android\android-sdk" 15
____________________
</DW>
'
<DW>
____________________
ERROR: console error
    context: Dreamweaver.exe::GetExitCodeProcess
    code: 1
    message: Incorrect function.


____________________
</DW>
ERROR: Clone failed
OPERATION CANCELED
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\Configuration\NativeAppFramework\apache-ant
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe kill-server
____________________
</DW>
* server not running *


<DW>
____________________
ERROR: console error
    context: Dreamweaver.exe::GetExitCodeProcess
    code: 1
    message: Incorrect function.`enter code here`


____________________
</DW>
```

I'm new to this I cannot detect what is wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver was corrupted by virus. Had to uninstall and reinstall it. Problem solved.